# Did they check the ticket anytime in HP?

Tags: harry-potter, books

It's something that I'm not sure if it was put in the books or was left outside the book for people to guess but... In any moment of the books, during the travel from the train between King Cross and Hogwarts, did they ask or checked the ticket? I remember the scene on first year/book that Hagrid almost forgot to give Harry the ticket, even when he did not tell about the 9 3/4, but I'm not sure if it was mentioned if they really need the ticket.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I was not sure. As I was more or less thinking that the only adults in the train are the Train Driver and the one that sells sweets and did not know if they even checked the tickets.

Comment: In the first book the tickets don't get inspected.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, on at least one occasion there's a "ticket inspector" on the Muggle side of the platform barrier.

> *When the ticket inspector signalled to Harry, Ron and Hermione that it
> was safe to walk through the magical barrier between platforms nine
> and ten, however, he found a surprise awaiting him on the other side:
> a group of people standing there to greet him who he had not expected
> at all.*
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix</sup></sub>

One assumes that a ticket inspector would be inspecting tickets.

Comment: Also the Hogwarts Express leaves from King's Cross. I believe King's Cross has ticket gates before you can get on the platforms.  So they at least would require muggle train tickets.

Comment: Why would there be a ticket inspector checking tickets on the way **out**? He was just controlling the flow of departing students, right?